# Writing a routing program, recursion difficulty in Java

Tags: java

So I am writing a program to route a person from one stop to another stop on a subway system. Here's the idea:

- take the starting stop and figure out what lines it's on. Then check if it's on the same line as the target stop
- if it is then print the path needed. This part actually works I've tested it.
- if not then move one stop down and up on each line and do the same check.

It gives me a Stack Overflow that I could not resolve. Tried to debug to no avail.

```
public ArrayList<Station> findRoutesBetween(Station start, Station target) {
    ArrayList<Station> path = new ArrayList<Station>();

    for (Route route : findRoutes(start)) {
        ArrayList<Station> stops = route.getStops();
        boolean sameRoute = findRoutes(target).contains(route);
        int stopIdstart = stops.indexOf(start);
        int stopIdtarget = stops.indexOf(target);
        if (sameRoute && stops.contains(start)) {
            if (stopIdtarget > stopIdstart) {
                path.addAll((stops.subList(stopIdstart, stopIdtarget + 1)));
                return path;
            } else {
                List<Station> temp = stops.subList(stopIdstart, stopIdtarget + 1);
                Collections.reverse(temp);
                path.addAll(temp);
                return path;
            }
        } else {
            if (stopIdstart != stops.size() - 1) {
                System.out.println("hh");
                ArrayList<Station> t = findRoutesBetween(stops.get(stopIdstart + 1), target);
                System.out.println(t.toString());
            }
            if (stopIdstart != 0) {
                System.out.println("hh");
                ArrayList<Station> t = findRoutesBetween(stops.get(stopIdstart - 1), target);
                System.out.println(t.toString());
            }
        }

    }
    return path;
}
```

The function findroutes() just returns all the lines that the stop is on.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`
 `at project.Map.findRoutesBetween(Map.java:50)`
 `at project.Map.findRoutesBetween(Map.java:55)` These line numbers are where the recursive call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation does not ignore the stations you have already checked or proceeded. This means that at some point you might go from station A to station B via a given route. Then when you are at station B you check all the possible stations and see station A again. Then you are back at station A again and start all over and find station B again. Now you are jumping back and forth between these stations in endless recursive method calls, until your get an `StackOverflowError`.

Keep a list of stations you have already checked and do not check stations again when they are in the list. So you get something like:

> Okay, I'm at station K and see the stations R, G, W, Z, C, I and L based on the routes available. However, I skip the stations W, Z and C because I was already there. So lets check only the stations R, G, I and L next...

For debugging purposes you can print the arguments coming in into your method (or some data from the `Station` object like the station name). This way you might have noticed that you see the same stations repeat themselves going into your method.